# Close the menu when clicking on one of its items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

There is a website on next.js, there is a panel on it that comes out from behind the edge when the button is pressed. There is a menu inside the panel. The panel itself and the menu are different components. The task is to make the panel open and close when you click on the button, and close when you click on any menu item. If the menu component is removed, and its code is simply inserted into the panel code, then everything works. And if you make a separate menu component, it does not work. I made a custom hook, which is probably buggy in the menu component, although it does not give out any errors.

This is hook:

```
// hooks/useSlideScreen

import { useState, useEffect  } from "react";

export default function useSlideScreen() {
  const [slideScreenActive, setSlideScreenActive] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.className = slideScreenActive ?  'isSlideActive'  : ''
    });

  return { slideScreenActive, setSlideScreenActive };
}
```

The component of the outgoing panel, in it this hook works normally

```
// components/slideScreen

import styles from "@/styles/slideScreen.module.css"
import Nav from "./nav";

import useSlideScreen from '@/hooks/useSlideScreen'

const SlideScreen = () => {
    const {slideScreenActive, setSlideScreenActive} = useSlideScreen()

    const menuBtnClasses = [styles.menuBtn, "mainBtn", slideScreenActive ?  `${styles.active}`  : null].join(" ")
    const slideScreenClasses = [slideScreenActive ?  `${styles.slideScreen} ${styles.show}`  : `${styles.slideScreen}`, "dotsBg"].join(" ")



    return (
        <>
            <button
                className={menuBtnClasses}
                onClick={() => {
                    setSlideScreenActive(!slideScreenActive)
                }}
            >
                <span className={styles.burger}></span>
            </button>
            <div className={slideScreenClasses}>
                <div className="wrapper">

                    <Nav/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}




export default SlideScreen;
```

The menu component, where the hook should also work (when clicking on the menu item, the panel closes), but does not work

```
// components/nav

import Link from "next/link";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import useSlideScreen from '@/hooks/useSlideScreen'

import styles from "@/styles/header.module.css"

const Nav = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const routes = ['Blog', 'Work', 'Contact'];

    const {slideScreenActive, setSlideScreenActive} = useSlideScreen(false)

    return (
        <nav className={styles.headerNav}>
            <ul className={styles.headerMenu}>
                {routes.map((route) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={route} className={`${router.pathname === `/${route.toLowerCase()}` && 'text-red-400'}`}>
                            <Link href={`/${route.toLowerCase()}`} onClick={() => { setSlideScreenActive(!slideScreenActive) }}>{route}</Link>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )

}

export default Nav
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error in the Nav component's code. In the Link component, you are passing routes instead of route as the child element. This is causing the menu items to display as an array of all the routes instead of their respective route names. You should replace routes with route in the Link component, like this:

```
<Link href={`/${route.toLowerCase()}`} onClick={() => { setSlideScreenActive(!slideScreenActive) }}>{route}</Link>
```

Also, in the Nav component, you are initializing the useSlideScreen hook with a false argument, which is not needed since the default value of slideScreenActive is already 0 (which is equivalent to false). You should remove the argument and initialize the hook like this:

```
const {slideScreenActive, setSlideScreenActive} = useSlideScreen();
```

With these changes, the Nav component should work as expected, and clicking on a menu item should close the panel.